# why is the limit not working in split method?

Tags: javascript, split

i am in a situation in which i have to split only till the first occurrence of the character `|`. now suppose i have a string say `var str =  "cat|bird|cow"`, i want this to break down it into

`['cat', 'bird|cow']`

so to do this i used the `split` method of string. as in the tutorials of `MDN` and in the book `Javascript: The Good Parts`, there is written that this method takes two parameters, one is the `separator` and the other is `limit`.

and this is the ideal method for me. but when, just for experiment, i tested this in google console i got unexpected results!

```
var a = "cat|bird|cow" // Undefined
a  // "cat|bird|cow"
a.split('|', a.indexOf('|')) // ['cat', 'bird', 'cow']
```

but i don't want this!

why is the limit not working? did the last update of javascript version removed it?

if 'no' then why it is not working?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `split`, `shift`, and `join`

```
var ar=str.split('|');
ar=[ar.shift(),ar.join('|')];
```

A Fiddle to play around.
http://jsfiddle.net/j8gkua24/

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of split defines how many items you want back:

```
a.split('|', 1) // ['cat']
a.split('|', 2) // ['cat', 'bird']
```

I'd probably split, slice and join:

```
var values = a.split('|');
var output = [values[0], values.slice(1).join('|')];

console.log(output); // ["cat", "bird|cow"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply;

```
var i = a.indexOf("|");
a = [a.substr(a, i), a.substr(i + 1)];

>> ['cat', 'bird|cow']
```